# jquery-minicolor-rails the selection not changing to wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a wheel based color picker. It is not changing. I have the following in the form and this in the js.

```
$('#white_label_main_theme_color').minicolors(control: 'wheel');
```

I also tried this:

```
$('#white_label_main_theme_color').minicolors({control: 'wheel'});
```

This is in the form:

```
<%= white.input :main_theme_color, as: :minicolors, :class => "minicolor" %>
```

But this is not working. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you included any necessary javascript files on the page, prior to using it?  Typically you would have something like this (i'm just using example filenames here):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.js", "jquery-minicolor.js" %>
<% javascript_tag do %>
  $(function() {
    $('#white_label_main_theme_color').minicolors({control: 'wheel'}); 
  });
<% end %>
```

I've not used minicolor so can't comment any further on the specifics (except to say that it normally would be curly (object) braces inside regular braces, as in your second attempt and my code above)

Also, make sure you do it first in a browser where you can get good feedback on javascript errors in the console, eg chrome, or firefox with firebug.

Comment: checked with firebug, there is no errors there. I also can confirm that normal mode is working without any problem. I am only not able to make the wheel mode work.

Comment: sorry.. It seems I have called it once in the javascript mode and another from the form. `<%= white.input :main_theme_color, as: :minicolors, :class => "minicolor" %>` should not have `as: :minicolors`